# Assign a bunch of animations to a variable in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm fairly new to jQuery so that's why I ask:

I have 3 conditional animations operating on three divs:

```
var viewport = $(window).width();
if ( viewport < 1400 ) { 
     $("#panel").animate({marginLeft:"-175px"}, 500 );
     $("#colleft").animate({width:"0px", opacity:0}, 400 );
     $("#showPanel").show("normal").animate({width:"28px", opacity:1}, 200);
     $("#colright").animate({marginLeft:"50px"}, 500);
}else{
     $("#colright").fadeIn('slow').animate({marginLeft:"200px"}, 200);
     $("#panel").fadeIn('slow').animate({marginLeft:"0px"}, 400 );
     $("#colleft").fadeIn('slow').animate({width:"190px", opacity:1}, 400 );
     $("#showPanel").animate({width:"0px", opacity:0}, 600).hide("slow");
}
```

As you can see, this is performing the animations based on viewport.

I have to repeat these conditionals on `$(window).resize(function() {` and `$("#hidePanel").click(function(e){`.

Do I have to repeat the code or can I assign them to a variable?

**EDIT**

The following function fails to work in the conditional.

```
function collapseMenu(){
    $("#panel").animate({marginLeft:"-175px"}, 500 );
    $("#colleft").animate({width:"0px", opacity:0}, 400 );
    $("#showPanel").show("normal").animate({width:"28px", opacity:1}, 200);
    $("#colright").animate({marginLeft:"50px"}, 500);
}

if ( viewport < 1400 ) { 
     collapseMenu();
}
```

Comment: Just wrap your above code in a function and call that from the 2 event handlers :)

Comment: Concerning our edit: Could you elaborate what "fails to work" mean? E.g. an Error message from the console?

Comment: @yoshi, ah, just kidding, I'm not sure if this is a WordPress issue but using '$' syntax is not an accepted token for the function. I have to write 'jQuery' instead. It works with the event listener if I declare jQuery(document.ready(function($){ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about wrapping it all in a function?

```
function runAnimation(){
    var viewport = $(window).width();
    if ( viewport < 1400 ) { 
        $("#panel").animate({marginLeft:"-175px"}, 500 );
        $("#colleft").animate({width:"0px", opacity:0}, 400 );
        $("#showPanel").show("normal").animate({width:"28px", opacity:1}, 200);
        $("#colright").animate({marginLeft:"50px"}, 500);
    }else{
        $("#colright").fadeIn('slow').animate({marginLeft:"200px"}, 200);
        $("#panel").fadeIn('slow').animate({marginLeft:"0px"}, 400 );
        $("#colleft").fadeIn('slow').animate({width:"190px", opacity:1}, 400 );
        $("#showPanel").animate({width:"0px", opacity:0}, 600).hide("slow");
    }
 }
```

So later you can simply call:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    runAnimation();
    //.... 
});

$("#hidePanel").click(function(e){
    runAnimation();
    //.... 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refactor your animation code as a function you can bind them to events in the following way.

```
$(window).resize(animateDivs);
$("#hidePanel").click(animateDivs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
function widthHanadler() {
    if ( viewport < 1400 ) { 
         $("#panel").animate({marginLeft:"-175px"}, 500 );
         $("#colleft").animate({width:"0px", opacity:0}, 400 );
         $("#showPanel").show("normal").animate({width:"28px", opacity:1}, 200);
         $("#colright").animate({marginLeft:"50px"}, 500);
    }else{
         $("#colright").fadeIn('slow').animate({marginLeft:"200px"}, 200);
         $("#panel").fadeIn('slow').animate({marginLeft:"0px"}, 400 );
         $("#colleft").fadeIn('slow').animate({width:"190px", opacity:1}, 400 );
         $("#showPanel").animate({width:"0px", opacity:0}, 600).hide("slow");
    }
}
```

and bind this function to your events:

```
$(window).resize(widthHanadler);
$("#hidePanel").click(widthHandler);
```